# 95% CI for the ICC in linear mixed effects model (multilevel model, hierarchical model)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, icc

I fitted a linear mixed effect model to predict the math score as the outcome, x= participant factor (nominal or ordinal) as the fixed effect, Schl is the random effect. Then I compared it with the simple linear regression model using `compare_performance`, and while the output gives the ICC, I was not sure how to calculate the 95% for it? (for coefficients I used `confint`confint and it did the job)

```
lm1<- lm(math~ gender, data= df)
lme1<- lmer(math~gender+(1|schl), data=df)

compare_performance(lm1,lme1)
```

the ICC was 0.15

Comment: what package (or other source) is `compare_performance()` from? Can you give a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

From this [gist from Peter Dahlgren](https://gist.github.com/peterdalle/7bce0bbebc13c36180fbbac1353a5353), taken in turn from a [CrossValidated answer by @Ashe](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184767/how-do-i-calculate-the-confidence-interval-of-an-icc), here is the crux:

```r
calc.icc <- function(y) {
  sumy <- summary(y)
  (sumy$varcor$id[1]) / (sumy$varcor$id[1] + sumy$sigma^2)
}
boot.icc <- bootMer(mymod, calc.icc, nsim=1000)
#Draw from the bootstrap distribution the usual 95% upper and lower confidence limits
quantile(boot.icc$t, c(0.025, 0.975))
```

You can (and should) check that this `calc.icc()` function gives the same results as your `compare_performance()` function. Since this uses parametric bootstrapping, you can substitute any ICC function you like as it long takes a fitted model as input and returns the ICC as a single numeric value.  (Also, because it uses PB, it will be slow; there are potentially faster approximate methods, but PB is reliable and easy to program.)